# How to Have Floating Title View in Scrollable Collection View Keep Its Y Position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Target is iOS 7+ iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, 6, 6+

By design, I have a scroll view that contains a collection view showing one row of cells only.

Using this set up, works well. The user can scroll right to left or up and down and compare the cells' content.

The scroll view supports the up/down scrolling. The collection view supports the left/right scrolling.

At the top of each collection view cell, I have a titleView (shown as "Some Title"). When the user scrolls up and down, I want the titleView for each cell always floating at the top of the screen. (See image below)

I am close to an answer. I use scrollViewDidScroll and set the titleView.origin.y to scrollView.contentOffset.y.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    for (CVKRecipeCollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {
        CGRect myFrame = cell.titleView.frame;

        myFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        cell.titleView.frame = myFrame;
    }
}
```

That works when the user scrolls up and down. However, when the user scrolls right/left, the titleView resets itself back to its original y position of 0.

How can I keep the titleView in that same y position that I specified in scrollViewDidScroll?

Code showing the issue is at: 
https://bitbucket.org/finneycanhelp/kata_collection_view_and_flow_layout/branch/floating-title-view

[CVKMainViewController](https://bitbucket.org/finneycanhelp/kata_collection_view_and_flow_layout/src/3d66a90126c14b5788d517e0eef52892423db82d/CollectionViewKata/CVKMainViewController.m?at=floating-title-view) has the scrollViewDidScroll method.

[image: Scrollable Collection View Cells with Floating Title View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the scrollView's contentOffset in the scrollViewDidScroll method. The collectionView is a scroll view. So this method is being called by both the scroll view that handles up/down and the collectionView which handles the left to right scrolling.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{    
    for (CVKRecipeCollectionViewCell *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {
        CGRect myFrame = cell.titleView.frame;

        myFrame.origin.y = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        cell.titleView.frame = myFrame;
    }
}
```